# Error Fetching http headers SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, soapfault

i have a problem with SOAP, havent found a real answer.

```
try {
    $objResponse = $objSoapClient->$strMethod($objMethod->getSoapRequest());
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {  
    GlobalLogState::write("exception with code(".$e->getCode()."): \n".$e->getMessage());
}
```

This is my simple SOAP request in try catch block.

I'm getting a SoapFault Exception:

```
Error Fetching http headers
```

What is the reason of that?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration that has worked for me was defining at my php script the following parameters:

```
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5000);
    $client = new \SoapClient($url,array(
    'trace' =>true,
    'connection_timeout' => 5000,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'keep_alive' => false,
));
```

Please, comment.

The most important parameter definition, as per my experience with this issue was ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5000);

During my tests I have defined the default_socket_timeout to 5 seconds and the error 'Error Fetching http headers' was raised instantaneously.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, we can increase the either increase the socket timeout `default_socket_time` in `php.ini` or add the `connection_timeout` parameter in the parameter array passed to the constructor of the SoapClient.

These parameters are in **seconds**.

1. In php.ini

   `default_socket_timeout = 120`

Alternatively, you can change from code

`ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);`

Note: The default socket timeout in php is 60 seconds.

2. `connection_timeout` parameter in SoapClient constructor

`$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('connection_timeout' => 120));`

Comment: The error comes after like 5 seconds - I seriously doubt it has anything to do with timeout. and the problem was not there a few weeks ago, with the old webservice setup. What ever I changed in my C# soap service setup, had an impact, but what?
I changed the response type from strongly typed to a XMLDocument. I even tried returning string.